# Run multiple instances of a python script and kill it

Tags: python, asynchronous, background, fastapi

Here is the scenario.
I'm creating an API using the fast-API framework in python.
The API will be used to run the async apps/scripts at the backend.
Like, telegram bots, discord bot etc having their own blocking loops. And each script will be run multiple times using different data or you can say multiple instances of each script will be running at the same time.
My question is what is the best solution to run the async apps on the backend so I may keep a track of the running instances of a bot/app/script at the backend and kill any instance of the script any time or see some other info about the script like for how long the script has been up to etc.

Comment: fast API can be run without a blocking mechanicsm.

Comment: I think I did not make myself clear. The problem is not handling the blocking scripts. The problem is handling the multiple scripts running and how to stop them when I want to?

Comment: running scripts? can you explain what this script is ?

Comment: Running scripts, I mean any python script with a blocking loop.

Comment: you can run blocking scripts using an executor, fire up 2-3 ThreadPoolExecutor and pass it into loop.run_in_executor method.

Comment: You can try something like celery.